# Selecting those Affected by a 1:1 relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

My teacher asked us to select from a 1:1 table called Employee; the supervisor and their role, and each employee they supervise with their role (employee is the primary key and those are the only 3 values in the table).

Comment: give a schema and your expected output.

Comment: Ideally DDL/DML statements to allow us to create test data.

Comment: google self join employee manager hierarchy

Comment: couple of points: 1) stackoverflow is an online source 2) homework is for learning

Answer (score 0):

A 1:1 relationship are two tables with only one possible matching id.

It assumes that each supervisors only has one employee. so your query would look something like this.

```
SELECT Employee.Name, Employee.Role, supervise.Name, supervise.Role
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN supervise 
ON Employee.EmployeeId = Supervise.EmployeeId
```

However, do note that in a real world context. This should have been a 1:N (One-To-Many) as each supervisors can have many employees.

Usually a 1:1 relationships are only used when you want to extended a table that you have no access or cannot modify. Otherwise, you would just add more columns to that original table. (or if you are working with a very old database system and you reach the max number of columns)

Comment: You're encouraging bad questions by answering one.

Comment: Thank you this was right in line with what I needed. It's definitely a little more unique than what I have worked with in internships

Comment: @FrankChen thats very good of you, but regardless of whether Conor is a beginner or not they can still ask a much better question, which is what we are trying to encourage. For example adding some sample data and expected results. Adding the table schema.

Comment: @Conor you welcome. Please clean up your question so it can help others. Your question has merit but do clean it up https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I do believe that a lot of student struggle with what is a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Also OP didn't engage with the people making comments. Everyone here wants to help but it takes effort from both sides, if people comment then the OP needs to respond either by doing what is asked or asking for clarification. Otherwise no learning is taking place.

Comment: @DaleK i.e. your asking a entry level student for a DDL/DML statements. If he is struggling on 1:1, i doubt he covered what a DDL/DML is. Conversely, if he clean up a bit the question. Students of his level googling his question will find an answer to what they are looking for.

Comment: @FrankChen it can all be googled - I'm totally self taught from scratch with no prior SQL experience. Alternatively OP can add a comment asking for clarification. No engagement tells us they don't care. Also do you honestly think they have learnt how to solve the problem their self from your answer? Or will they just use it blindly and wonder why it doesn't work for a similar but different problem?

Comment: @DaleK I honestly think so. but that is a debate for Meta.

Comment: @FrankChen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) might be of interest.